# How to upload file for robot framework with keyword "Choose File"

Tags: upload, attachment, robotframework, keyword, selenium2library

I have an attachment element:

`<span style="position: relative; z-index: 1;">
  <button class="attachment__browse" type="button" data-l10n-id="record_save_choose_file" id="c97" tabindex="10">Attach File</button>
</span>`

And i write script for file attach as:

```
Wait Until Page Contains Element    id=c97
Choose File    id=c97   C:\\Users\\NTQ\\My Pictures\\images.png
```

It doesn't work and show error:

> File 'C:\Users\NTQ\My Pictures\images.png' does not exist on the local file system.

I am sure that the locator and file_path are correct. Please help me fix this issue!

Answer (score 2):

`C:\\Users\\NTQ\\My Pictures\\images.png` this is the path you are using. Space in between `"My Pictures"` is the reason for it. Try to keep the path of the image which should not contain space in between any of the words.

Comment: I try again with script:
`Choose File    id=c97   C:\\images.png`
It works incorrect. This test case has been pass button that file has not attached. :(

Comment: generally, don't prefer id(locator) which contains numerical values. Since it may change dynamically. choose some other locator like jquery or any other